# Drop down menu filtering rows by column name - gsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that, unfortunately I can`t share but I can give an overview of what I`m trying to do.

I have a master sheet that is updated daily and another sheet that pulls the latest update with the following columns:

```
Have_click.          Have_impressions
TRUE                 TRUE
FALSE                TRUE
TRUE                 FALSE
TRUE                 FALSE
```

What I want to do is create 02 filters from a data validation drop down menu.
When I have "have_click" and "true" it will show all the data that are TRUE under the have_click column

I was trying to use a IF statement basically saying

```
=IF(B1="have_click",""," AND AE='"&B1&"'")
```

Where B1 is the true or false value
However, I can`t seem to make it work cause the "have_click" is a columnn name and is not a row value.

Does anybody knows how to fix that?

thank you

Comment: is it that you want to summon a column with specific header name which can change its column position from day to day?

Comment: The data changes it everyday but the columns name remains the same. What I wanted is to filter a value “True” or “false” from a specific header name. Like all data that is true under have_click column

Comment: Can you detail more what are you trying to do? If possible share a sheet with dummy data

Comment: yes, sure I made this file here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ALbr7S19LOdVzsa7zZ7gN1037xIX_fSCmXbztXDev7A/edit#gid=0

Comment: Whenever I change the filter on KPI and the value I need to filter the whole dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({'Página3'!A1:K}; "where Col"&MATCH(C1; 'Página3'!1:1; 0)&" = "&C2; 1)
```

[image]

or more stable:

```
=QUERY({'Página3'!A1:K}; 
 "where 1=1 "&IF((C1<>"")*(C2<>""); " 
    and Col"&MATCH(C1; 'Página3'!1:1; 0)&" = "&C2; ); 1)
```

Comment: I didn`t understand how that would work. Do you mind elaborate it?

Comment: thank you so much for your help here, it was super helpfull. Just a quick question, the Pagina3 doesnt work if is a query importing a range from another sheet. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: it would be: `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Página3!A1:K")}; 
 "where 1=1 "&IF((C1<>"")*(C2<>""); " 
    and Col"&MATCH(C1; IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Página3!1:1"); 0)&" = "&C2; ); 1)`